# HTML5 video not playing online in IE, but plays offline

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, html5-video, mp4

I'm trying to place HTML5 video into a webpage using multiple sources. It works fine in all browsers online and offline **except** all versions of IE when used online. I get *'Error: Unsupported video type of invalid file path'*.

Here's my code to populate a div of class 'vid'.

```
var vidArray = ['../video/test.ogv', '../video/test.mp4']
$('.vid').html('<video width="544" height="306" controls >
                <source src="'+vidArray[0]+'" type="video/ogg"/>
                <source src="'+vidArray[1]+'" type="video/mp4"/>
                </video>');
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Di you tried with WebM format? IE support it if codecs are installed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this is a codecs problem.

Check if your page not contains video  elements with invalid codecs strings. In particular, codecs="H.264, AAC" in  is not a valid codecs string.

Please see the W3C HTML5 author guidance at http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-author/the-source-element.html#attr-source-type for examples of valid H.264 video and AAC audio codecs strings.

Check at this question too.
[The html5 video shows at local but not online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406554/the-html5-video-shows-at-local-but-not-online?rq=1)