# Difference between OGV and OGG

Tags: html, video, html5-video

I recently encountered a problem regarding the OGV file extension in Firefox. When using the extension in the  source it returns a "No video with supported format or MIME types found" error in the player. But when just changing the extension from OGV to OGG it works. I didn't add the AddType in Apache.

Are the extensions interchangeable? Why does changing the extension from OGV to OGG works? Just a little confused.

Comment: OGV is for video, OGG is for audio, but they have the same MIME. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check if your ogv-file plays in firefox (simply drag'n'drop the videofile to an open firefox-window). if it is playing normally, check if your server supports the `MIME types` and add them to your `.htaccess file`. [check my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406554/the-html5-video-shows-at-local-but-not-online/9410136#9410136)

Comment: Adding AddType to .htaccess seems to be not working for me the last time, but I'll give it another try. But if I just change the OGV to OGG extension, there is no problem with that right? Except for the fact that it's not pretty.